# Firebase authentication and store user in MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, firebase

I want to know how I can register a user using Firebase authentication, and then proceed to store the user in a MySQL database as well for later use.

I am currently authenticating the user using Firebase, but am not sure how to go about calling a Nodejs API to query the MySQL database.

All the examples I have seen to  store users in MySQL are calling the API from the form action itself. However, I want to first authenticate the user with Firebase.

If someone has experience with this I would appreciate the help.

```
const signupForm = document.querySelector('#sign-up-form');
signupForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //get user info
    const username = signupForm['signup-username'].value;
    const email = signupForm['signup-email'].value;
    const password = signupForm['signup-password'].value;

    //signup the user
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
        //createUser function returns the user credentials
        user = auth.currentUser;
    }).then(function () {
        user.updateProfile({
            displayName: username
        })
    }).catch((error) => {
        //Handle errors
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
            alert('The password is too weak.');
        } else {
            alert(errorMessage);
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some sort of backend to send the user and then use Express or some other server make the query and save to MySQL. You can't do it from the client because it's insecure.

eg:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(async (user) {
        user.updateProfile({
            displayName: username
        })
        const result = await axios.post('/api/saveUser/', user, config)
    })
```